# Yii Framework Context in PHP Pthread Class

Tags: php, yii, php-pthread

I'm working on [PHP Pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php). I have written a class which inherits the "Thread" class. This class does not recognize the Yii (1.x) framework context. I cannot use any of the Yii framework components or models. I have made sure the thread class should reside in the Yii framework's accessible paths defined in the "import" in configuration.

Here is an example how I wrote the thread class.

```
  <?php

    class MultiThreaded extends Thread {


            public function __construct(){

            }

            public function run(){
                       echo Yii::app()->basePath;
            }


    }
```

Update:

Here is the importer array in Yii config.

```
'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'application.components.multithreaded-operations.*',
        'application.components.google_api_Lib.src.*',
        'application.controllers.*',
        'application.extensions.yii-mail.*',
        'application.extensions.*',
        'application.commands.*',

    ),
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Arfeen

Comment: Can you show **config** and path to **MultiThreaded**?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I just updated my question with import array. application.components.multithreaded-operations is the path for my Thread class.

Comment: So what is the error? As I understood, when you create new instance of **MultiThreaded** something is wrong? `$test = new MultiThreaded();`.

Comment: @Danila Ganchar the problem is inside the class Yii object context cannot be recognised while this class already autoloaded by framework.

Comment: Have you tried with different version of yii??

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pthreads in your system.

### **For Wampp (Windows)**

1. Find out what is your 'PHP Extension Build' version by using phpinfo(). You can use this - `http://localhost/?phpinfo=1`
2. Download the pthreads that matches your php version (32 bit or 64 bit) and php extension build (currently used VC11). Use this link for download - http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/
3. Extract the zip -
     Move php_pthreads.dll to the 'bin\php\ext\' directory.

   Move pthreadVC2.dll to the 'bin\php\' directory.

   Move pthreadVC2.dll to the 'bin\apache\bin' directory.

   Move pthreadVC2.dll to the 'C:\windows\system32' directory.
4. Open php\php.ini and add
     extension=php_pthreads.dll

Now restart server and you are done.

### For LINUX SYSTEM'S:

1) Download PHP sources and Unpack PHP

2) Download PEAR
     wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
     php go-pear.phar

3) Download pthreads
Get PECL extension (PECL is a repository for PHP Extensions)

## pecl install pthread-0.4.4

4) Unpack pthreads
copy pthread-0.4.4  to  php/ext
(for ./configure allow  add option --enable-pthreads)

## mv build/php-src-master/ext/pthreads-master    build/php-src-master/ext/pthreads

5)  Reconfigure sources

## ./buildconf --force

## ./configure --help | grep pthreads

You should see the appropriate --enable-pthreads option listed as a result, if you do not, then

## rm -rf aclocal.m4

## rm -rf autom4te.cache/

## ./buildconf --force

6) Build PHP
Compile PHP source code
Add:

## ./configure --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-pthreads

7) Installing PHP

## make

## sudo make install

8) Update php.ini
Add in php.ini
extension=pthreads.so
Include_path = “/usr/local/lib/php”

9) Check Modules
php -m (check pthread loaded)

10) Test Thread Class

## php SimpleTest.php

This [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php) will explain better.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: I posted this question after testing basic phthread scripts (so pthread already installed in the system). As I mentioned earlier, the question is regarding Yii framework with pthread. Thanks :) .

Comment: @Arfeen : As per my knowledge, There is nothing to do with Yii. If we install it in our system then we can use it in any framework. Have you tried with \Thread?

Comment: I have already used and tested those examples. They are working with out framework. But the problem is, framework context get unset and destroyed inside pthread inherited classes. I hope you got my point.

Comment: @Arfeen Have you solved your thread issue in yii? I have faced samethings. If you solved that could you please post answer in your own question. That will helps to other developers. Thanks...